# Binding data from API to gridview in Flutter on button click?

Tags: flutter

How can I Bind data from API to gridview in Flutter on button click?
Lets say I have  a search button that calls a search API, after I press search I will receive a JSON response, after that I need to show it on a gridview.

Answer (score 0):

The API call is most likely going to come back through a Future, so the simplest is to use a FutureBuilder.  But if you can follow it, I'd use a RiverPod FutureProvider, because it will cache the results and also has this cool .when thing that eliminates the need for a FutureBuilder.